# How to divide up/encode a number into a set of bitarrays that factor/multiply/etc to get the original number

Tags: numbers, bit-manipulation

I found somewhere a "decimal byte" representation of the number `14852543` being `226 161 191`. I assume this is because it somehow factors or multiplies or something into this number, but I'm not sure how it's done.

The first part of the question is how to convert those byte values back into the number. The second part of the question is, how to break a number into a set of **bitarrays** (not bytes), that accomplish the same thing as above. So for example, instead of 3 8-bit numbers, it might be 5 7-bit numbers, or 12 3-bit numbers. Wondering what the equation or algorithm is that can do that.

Comment: 14852543 = 0x00e2a1bf, split into 4 bytes in decimal that would be 0, 226, 161, 191. It only looks weird and complicated in decimal, it's actually just concatenation.

Comment: Oh ok, nice. Well then my question is about the factoring part then :)

Comment: The inverse of concatenation is splitting, so splitting the binary representation into blocks of 8 or whatever other length you're interested in

Answer (score 0):

Taking 14852543 as the example input.

**Case 1 [ 12 3-bit numbers ]** :

Step 0 : Setup' the bits group. 12 x [000] . Or [ 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 ]

Step 1 : [convert 14852543 to binary](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=convert+14852543+to+binary). Should get 111000101010000110111111 .

Step 2 : 111000101010000110111111 to [ 000 000 000 000 111 000 101 010 000 110 111 111 ] .

Step 3 : [ 000 000 000 000 111 000 101 010 000 110 111 111 ] to **[ 0 0 0 0 7 0 5 2 0 6 7 7 ]**

**Case 2 [ 5 7-bit numbers ]** :

Step 0 : Setup' the bits. 5 x [0000000] . Or [ 0000000 0000000 0000000 0000000 0000000 ]

Step 1 : [convert 14852543 to binary](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=convert+14852543+to+binary). Should get 111000101010000110111111 .

Step 2 : 111000101010000110111111 to [ 0000000 0000111 0001010 1000011 0111111 ] .

Step 3 : [ 0000000 0000111 0001010 1000011 0111111 ] to **[ 0 7 10 67 63 ]**

**Case 3 [ 3 8-bit numbers ]** :

Step 0 : Setup' the bits. 3 x [00000000] . Or [ 00000000 00000000 00000000 ]

Step 1 : [convert 14852543 to binary](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=convert+14852543+to+binary). Should get 111000101010000110111111 .

Step 2 : 111000101010000110111111 to [ 11100010 10100001 1011111 ] .

Step 3 : [ 11100010 10100001 1011111 ] to **[ 226 161 191 ]**

---

Hope it answers... ( :